# How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect and useParams React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';
const Todo = () => {
  const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState();
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
// I wanted to fetch the data for the specific id from the jsonPlaceholder url to practice 

    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        const responseTodo = res.data;
        setTodoDetails(responseTodo);
      });

  }, [])//the console said the error is here but i don't know what to do 
// the error is "  Line 17:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"
  const { id: todoId, userId, title, completed } = todoDetails || {}
  return (
    <div>{`this is the todoes componets and the id is  ${todoId} , ${userId}, ${title}, ${completed}`}</div>
  )
}
export default Todo;
```

**I'm very new in the developer world i just started learning JS. I was asked to do a project using react js any tips would really help me out **

Comment: `}, [])` => `}, [id])` (please google error messages first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about COMPONENTDIDUPDATE in react hooks, you can learn more about state and lifecicle concept in https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html. Your code must be like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        const responseTodo = res.data;
        setTodoDetails(responseTodo);
      });

  }, [id])
```

Comment: the warning is gone but it wont display anything i checked the console and it says this"Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useParams) is not a function " the line in which the error is said to be on the line where "const { id } = useParams();"
i just had to import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect uses a dependency array as the second argument to watch changes, so basically if you leave the dependency array empty the useEffect will only run once when the component mounts.

If you add a property or more in the dependency array it will run everytime those values change.

In this case your useEffect is using the id to make the api call but I'll only run once, the warning is telling you that, so if the id prop changes the useEffect won't run

Add this if you want the useEffect to be run everytime the id changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Rest of the code.  
  // Adding the id here will make this effect to run everytime the id changes.
  }, [id])
```

Comment: the warning is gone but it wont display anything i checked the console and it says this"Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useParams) is not a function " the line in which the error is said to be on the line where "const { id } = useParams();" i just had to import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";